# JS parallax multiple elements position

Tags: javascript, css, parallax

I have three elements on which I wanna use a parallax effect, but I have to change each of their position in order to have the picture at the right place (section) from the top. I tried with some "if" to change the value of the "paddTop" but only the last parallax is working when i do that. Here is my code :

(function (){

```
var parallax = document.querySelectorAll(".paralax, .parallax2, .parallax3"),
  speed = 0.35;

window.onscroll = function (){
  [].slice.call(parallax).forEach(function (el,i){

    if (parallax==document.querySelectorAll(".parallax")){
      var paddTop = 1500;
    }
    if (parallax==document.querySelectorAll(".parallax2")){
      var paddTop = 2200;
    }
    if (parallax==document.querySelectorAll(".parallax3")){
      var paddTop = 3000;
    }

    var windowYOffset = window.pageYOffset-paddTop, 
        elBackgrounPos = "50% " + (windowYOffset * speed) + "px";

    el.style.backgroundPosition = elBackgrounPos;
    });
};
```

})();

If anyone has an idea of why only the last is working please let me know.
Am not very good at JS yet so maybe it will be a little mistake, but it would would really help me.

Thank you !

[Code updated at my next post below]

Answer (score 0):

```
var parallax = document.querySelectorAll(".parallax"),
    parallax = document.querySelectorAll(".parallax2"),
    parallax = document.querySelectorAll(".parallax3"),
    speed = 0.35;
```

With that `parallax` will always hold the value of the last line (`document.querySelectorAll(".parallax3")`) because you are assigning it three times.

I guess you mean something like that:

```
var parallax = document.querySelectorAll(".paralax, .parallax2, .parallax3");
```

to select ALL of those elements.

Honestly, It is very difficult to guess what you are trying to achieve, because the code you provide (provided) doesn't make any sense to me.

The first issue was that you are assign the value to `parallax`, three times, so guessed you would like to have a list to iterate over, what `[].slice.call(parallax).foreach(…)` suggests.

But within the callback you simply compare `parallax`, which is globally set, to result of `document.querySelectorAll()`, to assign a value to `paddTop`.

If you want to assign a value to `paddTop` depending on the result of `document.querySelectorAll()` you do not to iterate the `parallax` list, you even don't need to setup the variable `parallax` at all, because you just check if there are some elements match your query.

So, what do you want to achieve?

Something like that:

```
var parallaxes = [
    [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".parallax")),
    [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".parallax2"))
];


parallaxes.forEach(function(elements, idx){
    if (idx == 0) {
        elements.forEach(function(element) {
            element.style.backgroundPosition = '…'
        })
    }

    if (idx == 0) {
        elements.forEach(function(element) {
            element.style.backgroundPosition = '…'
        })
    }

})
```

Comment: Yes i've tried that, was a nonsense mistake from me, so now I am keeping the

Comment: var parallax = document.querySelectorAll(".paralax, .parallax2, .parallax3"); but the code is still not running, there is another mistake somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help,

As you said yes I was pretty confused even myself about my code so I can understand you didn't get it.
I simply want to have several parallaxes with a different value of paddTop (1500, 1700 and 3200 less than the pageYOffset).

Looking at your answer i've tried this, running the "if" with the id which makes more sense. I'll also put the html and css so you can have a better look and understand.

```
(function (){

var parallax = document.querySelectorAll(".parallax"),
    speed = 0.35;

window.onscroll = function (){
  [].slice.call(parallax).forEach(function (element,i,id){
    if (id == "parllax-1") {
            var windowYOffset = window.pageYOffset-1500; 
    }

    if (id == "parllax-2") {
            var windowYOffset = window.pageYOffset-1700;
    }

    if (id == "parllax-3") {
           var windowYOffset = window.pageYOffset-3200;
    }

    elBackgrounPos = "50% " + (windowYOffset * speed) + "px";
    element.style.backgroundPosition = elBackgrounPos;
  })
};
  })();
```

Here is the CSS :

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 55vh;
}

section#parallax-1 {
  background-image: url(../images/cabaneL.jpg);
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
section#parallax-2...
```

And the HTML :

```
<section class="parallax" id="parallax-1"><!-- down in the page #parallax-2 and #parallax-3 --> 
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid flex">
    <div class="absomid-cbp white7 corner"><a href="..."></a>
      ...
    </div><!-- END absomid --> 
  </div><!-- END grid --> 
</div>
</section>
```

Even though it's still not working :(